# Using lambda inside Ruby method

Tags: ruby

I'm just starting with `Ruby` and I hit an issues which I feel is important for the language so I don't want to just pass it. I would really appreciate answer which includes not only a working example but at least brief explanation where I went wrong with mine.

So **first** step is having this method:

```
def filter (arr)
    arr.each do |e|
        puts e if e % 2 != 0
    end
end 

filter [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

And the result as expected is:

> 1 3 5 [Finished in 0.2s]

**Second** I tried this one:

```
def filter (arr)
    arr.each do |e|
        puts e if yield(e)
    end
end 

filter ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) { |n| n.odd? }
```

And I got the same result:

> 1 3 5 [Finished in 0.2s]

**Third** I want to do this using a lambda. Ultimately I want ti invoke the `filter` method like so `filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], &is_odd)`. But since I can't still figure it out I am currently stuck at this:

```
is_odd = lambda { |n| puts n if n.odd? }

def filter ()
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    arr.each do |e|
        is_odd(e)
    end
end 

filter &is_odd
```

And I got the following error:

> `block in filter': undefined method`is_odd' for main:Object
>   (NoMethodError)

It kind of makes sense to me that this is not working since, if I define the lambda inside the `filter` function and use it like so:

```
def filter ()
    is_odd = lambda { |n| puts n if n.odd? }
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    arr.each &is_odd
end 

filter
```

I'm again getting the expected behavior, but I am following a tutorial and it seems like it should be possible to declare `is_odd` outside the `filter` method and invoke filter like so `filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], &is_odd)`.

I would like to know if indeed it is possible to do use lambda this way and if yes, where did my logic fail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like to know if indeed it is possible to do use lambda this way

Yes.

> and if yes, where did my logic fail?

By passing the lambda as `&is_odd`, you're turning it into a block of the method. So, use it as a block. In the snippet above you show that you know about `yield`. Here's another way of calling the passed block.

```
is_odd = lambda { |n| puts n if n.odd? }

def filter(&block)
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    arr.each do |e|
        block.call(e)
    end
end 

filter(&is_odd)
# >> 1
# >> 3
# >> 5
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about this option. Is it OK to include lambdas in method definition?

Comment: @Leron: the `&block`? It's not your lambda anymore. In this case, it's a Proc object, which is made from the method's block (which, in turn, comes from your lambda). And yes, it's a common thing to see in ruby code.

Comment: Probably worth noting that you don't use parentheses like that when calling a lambda, hence the NoMethodError. You use brackets (`some_lamba[arg]`), `#call` (`some_lambda.call(arg)`), or  dot-parentheses (`some_lambda.(arg)`).

Comment: @muistooshort: ah yes, totally.